# Deriving the First order response of a sensor

Tags: mechanical-engineering, sensors

I'm trying to derive the first order response of a sensor with step input. However, I'm stuck at step just before conducting the Laplace transform. In the following image, how is the left side equal to the right side? I know the right side equation is necessary to obtain to perform Laplace transform. [image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you question: are you asking what the "." should be or why `A*K/((\tau*s + 1)*s) = A*K * (1/s - 1/(s-(-1/\tau))`? The latter is simple maths, the former requires more information on what the "." is.

Comment: Yes I mean how is A*K/((\tau*s + 1)*s) = A*K * (1/s - 1/(s-(-1/\tau))!

Comment: [Partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple maths. Starting from the RHS to get to the LHS:

$$
AK \left[ \frac{1}{s} - \frac{1}{s - \frac{-1}{\tau}} \right]
= AK \left[ \frac{1}{s} - \frac{1}{s + \frac{1}{\tau}} \right]
= AK \left[ \frac{1}{s} - \frac{\tau}{\tau s +1} \right]
= AK \left[ \frac{\tau s + 1 - \tau s}{s(\tau s +1)} \right]
= \frac{AK}{s(\tau s + 1)}
$$